# Spring 5.1.2 PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver detects files on root of jar

Tags: java, spring, classpath, classloader

I was reading spring docs regarding classpath* and I found :

> Please note that classpath*: when combined with Ant-style patterns will only work reliably with at least one root directory before the pattern starts, unless the actual target files reside in the file system. This means that a pattern like classpath*:*.xml will not retrieve files from the root of jar files but rather only from the root of expanded directories. This originates from a limitation in the JDK’s ClassLoader.getResources() method which only returns file system locations for a passed-in empty string (indicating potential roots to search).

when I was trying this locally I was confused that it worked on root of jars , example :

test.txt resource exists in test2 root ( which is the class I run the application from ) , and there is also test.txt on test which is dependency on test2

Project test2  :

```
    @RunWith(JUnit4.class)
public class TestDriver {
@Test
public void test() throws IOException {

    PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver resolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(resolver.getResources("classpath*:*test.txt")));
    Enumeration<URL> enumeration= this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResources("");
    int count=0;
    while(enumeration.hasMoreElements()){
       URL url= enumeration.nextElement();
       System.out.println(url.getFile());
        count++;
    }
    System.out.println(count);
}
```

}

output :

[URL [jar:file:/C:/.../.m2/repository/com/test/1.0-SNAPSHOT/test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/test.txt]] --- > **The question how this text file detected while it's on the root of a jar , according to docs it shouldn't be detected**

from "this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResources("")" there is only 2 roots ( test jar is not part of them ) :

/..../test2/target/test-classes/

/..../test2/target/classes/

2

Comment: @davidxxx aaah you got my question wrong. I'm asking about the file on the jar how it's detected. because according to spring doc files on root won't be detected " will not retrieve files from the root of jar files but rather only from the root of expanded directories "

Comment: I delete my comments like not useful any longer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The doc refers to the reliability of the resource lookup in this specific case.
You can also read at the end of this warning part of the [`PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver` javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/support/PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.html) (emphasis is mine) :

> WARNING: Note that "classpath*:" when combined with Ant-style patterns
>   will only work reliably with at least one root directory before the
>   pattern starts
>
> ...
>
> **This `ResourcePatternResolver` implementation is trying to mitigate the
>   jar root lookup limitation** through URLClassLoader introspection and
>   "java.class.path" manifest evaluation; however, without portability
>   guarantees.

It seems that it works for your case.

Comment: aaah so it's at least with no guarantees , very nice answer.